# Dell XPS not starting

Tags: laptop

I got a Dell XPS laptop. The computer has been off for a while and today I decided to find a new use for it however it didn't turn on.

I have charged it with the power cord and with the USB-C via the docking station with no success. when I hit the power, the backlight of the keyboard lights up for a minute then it shuts down completely.

Any advice on how to move forward, I don't want to spend money on a new battery or power supply if that's not the issue, the computer was clean and bearly used, it was purchased new however it's out of warranty now.

Comment: "off for a while" - how long is 'a while'? Chances are the battery has drained beyond recovery. However, one shot; put it on charge for a whole 24h & see if it will boot, with the power still connected too.

Comment: “when I hit the power, the backlight of the keyboard lights up for a minute then it shuts down completely.” - Sounds like the battery is dead.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the user had the wrong power supply connected to the system, once it was replaced the issues went away.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1236918)